# C# Serialize unknown type Object to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, stream, memorystream

I've been searching around on how to serialize unknown type of Object but I can't find any solution for it and I found that It's really not that straight forward.

Class :

```
    public Vector3D<int> rentedVMPosition;
    public Value<uint> saveFileVersion;
    public Value<int> score;
    public Value<int> selectedInventorySlot;
    public Value<long> selectedSpawnPointKey;
    public Value<int> skillPoints;
    public Skills skills;
    public MemoryStream skillStream;
    .......... Etc
```

Full Class = https://github.com/Karlovsky120/7DaysSaveManipulator/blob/master/source/1.15.0.1/PlayerDataFile.cs

[Object Overview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrRT2.jpg)

Inside the object there's MemoryStream Object which seems like not possible to serialize, when I try to serialize it with JsonConvert.Serialize by **newtonsoft.json**, it will shows "Timeouts are not supported on this stream" error.

anyway , I've tried with excluding the MemoryStream object while serializing it with JsonConvert.Serialize it will produce JSON with empty value such as 
{"example" : "" , "asdsada" : "" } etc... I think it's due to unknown type.

Please anyone have any idea to serialize this object, help will very much appreciated?

Comment: How are you ignoring, using `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, that's the ideal mechanism

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, are you trying to say that I suppose to apply the [JsonIgnore] attribute to every class  to solve this problem?

Comment: @campin No, you apply it above `public MemoryStream skillStream`.

Comment: It would be like this (Part of Newtonsoft Json):

[JsonIgnore]
public MemoryStream skillStream;

Comment: thanks again, anyway , there's some strange issues where after serialize the object, field name existed but it has null value, I suspect that it is because unknown type, eventually what I do is I declare a dynamic object and reassign the object with toString() then serialize with JsonConvert so that the value is shown after JSOn serialization, without that it just just a null value, is there anyway to fix this issues without declaring a dynamic object and assign with toString() ? because there's too many fields and there's many nested object in the object.